# why the inner function can't get variable in outer scope in python

Tags: python, variables, scope, environment-variables

```
def foo():
    m = 3
    def bar():
        print(m) # code 1
        m=4 # code 2
    bar()
foo()
```

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'm' referenced before assignment

Why do I get the `UnboundLocalError`? I know `bar` can't change the value of `m`, but shouldn't `bar`just be able to get the value of `m`?

And when I try the code `1/code 2` separately, it all works.

Comment: Your indentation is not correct, please fix it first!

Comment: If a function contains an assignment to a variable, and there is no `global` or `nonlocal` declaration for it, then that variable is a local - even at points in the function before the assignment.

Comment: @ᴀʀᴍᴀɴ Thanks! Format really matters.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks, 
I roughly
understood.It really helps.

Answer (score 3):

Since the inner function `bar` has an assignment `m=4`, `m` is considered as a local variable, for whole of the function. But at the point you invoke `print(m)`, `m` is not yet created. So you get the error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'm' referenced before assignment`.

In Python 3, you can fix the code by declaring `m` to be `nonlocal` in the inner scope. This avoids placing `m` in the global scope (which is also an option in both Python 2 and 3 using the `global` keyword in place of `nonlocal`). The following code works in Python 3:

```
def foo():
    m = 3
    def bar():
        nonlocal m
        print(m) # code 1
        m=4 # code 2
    bar()
foo()
```

Comment: So the compiler look at the whole of the function bar and know there is a local m, but isn't python executed line by line？I guess the process of py->pyc did it( look at the whole of the function bar), Then the machine execute the pyc line by line.(I search the Internet)  the Sorry I am a newbie, thanks!